# How do I know who is using my pictures in a fake Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

Recently I came to know someone is created a fake facebook account using other name and in that account, my all pictures are uploaded which are uploaded to my original fb account. suddenly I reported against that account and within hours that account has been removed. But I wanted to know who is the person because he is very near to me that very sure. I also noted that 2 pictures uploaded in fake account which is not available in my original account, may be he/she got that pictures from my Whatsapp. There are so many questions in my mind and I am not able to find out the answer. please help me out.

Comment: Seems like someone is just messing with you. Set your profile to private for now until they get bored of being creep and stalking you.

Comment: I doubt we can help here. It's you who can help yourself. Check and update your privacy setting(mostly to private) on all social networking profile.

Comment: ankit Kumar, from the very first day I am very much concern regarding privacy. And I always share pictures only with friends never shared any pictures publically.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming.